# ActionView::MissingTemplate Error when trying to create new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, templates, coffeescript, actionview

I am hitting the error "ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/suites, application/suites with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml, :rabl]}." when I tried to post (create new) to suites (/suites.json). The snippets of codes are below.

Can anyone advise me on how I can resolve this? Thanks!

SuitesController.rb

```
def create

  @suite = Suite.new
  @suite.text = params[:suite][:text]
  @suite.description = params[:suite][:description]
  @suite.remote_image_url = params[:suite][:image_url]

  if @suite.save
    render json: Suite.standard_to_json(@suite)
  else
    render json: @suite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Suites.rb

```
class Suite
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :text, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :image_url, type: String

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :text
  validates_presence_of :image

  def self.standard_to_json(suites)
    suites.to_json
  end

end
```

[image]

Suites.js.coffee

```
class Entities.Suite extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: "/suites"


class Entities.SuitesCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Entities.Suite
  url: "/suites"

API =
  getSuites: (cb) ->
    suites = new Entities.SuitesCollection
    suites.fetch
      success: ->
        cb suites
      error: ->
        cb suites

  newSuite: (suite, cb) ->
    $.post "/suites.json",
      suite: suite
    .success (suite) ->
      cb (suite)

App.reqres.setHandler "suites:get", (cb) ->
  API.getSuites(cb)

App.reqres.setHandler "suite:add", (suite , cb) ->
  API.newSuite(suite, cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the conclusion of your `create` method, you need to have a `redirect_to` that sends the user to a different page (e.g., an `edit.html.erb`). If you don't do this, the controller will POST the data, and then try to render a `create.html.erb` page, which it can't find.

Comment: But i do have a suites.haml.html created. Won't that suffice?